# A function to replace circle when it's out of the screen

Tags: python, tkinter, graphics

The problem is that I need to write a function which will move the drawn circle around the field, an when the circle is going to leave the field it must appear from the opposite side of it (like that snake game on nokia phones, you know)
My progress at this:

```
def move_wrap(canvas, obj, move):
    canvas.move(obj, move[0], move[1])
    #  if <left the field>:
           # <move to the opposite edge>
```

I am sorry for such a question, UI is really not my thing. But I'm asked to write a game on tkinter, and I have to learn how it all works

Comment: Reading minds is not really *our* thing here, so you'll need to provide a lot more context and code to get your question answered. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Try `if <object is on the right edge of the screen>: <move it to the left edge of the screen>`. It will only take a few `if` statements.